# Spring Boot Rest API - input file + endpoints

Tags: java, json, rest

I have common question about architecture I should use for my specific problem.

I have .TSV file with some informations and my task is to create REST API app that will consume this .TSV file and there will be 3 REST API endpoints. Each endpoint will return JSON data I processed from .TSV file.

My question is: Should I crate some POST method that will upload the TSV file and I will save it eg to the session and do the logic with using the API Endpoints?

Or should I POST the content of TFS file as JSON in every request to the specific endpoint?

I dont know how to glue it all together.

There is no requirement fot the DB. The program will be tested just with numerous requests through the API and I dont know how to process or store the .TSV content in my app so one user could call all three endpoint sequentially above the same data without reuploading the TSV file.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to upload the file and then do the processing on server.  The file will upload in one request and it's better rather than  send multiple request.

Comment: How to solve that one upload will be associated with one request so the server could handle many of them? And each user of the API could call API methods above his own file?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the solution will depend on the size of the file. Storing the file in the memory can not be a good approach if the file is very large. And also, saving the file in a session may not be good, because if you need to scale your service in the future, you will not be able to do it. Even storing the file in a /tmp directory can also be a bad approach, because the solution continues to be not scalable.

It will be a good idea using a Storage Service like AWS S3 or Google Firebase or any other related. When you would call one of your three RESTs, your application will verify if that file was not yet processed, read that file, process anything you want and save the result to your S3 Bucket (If you don't want to save the processed files, you can use a retention policy on S3 to delete the file after X period of time).
And only after this, you will return the result. As you can see, this is a synchronous solution.

If the file processing need a lot of CPU and takes so long, you will need an asynchronous solution. So instead of processing the files directly when you call the REST API, you will have to create another application that will read that file from S3, process it and save it. All asynchronously. And your REST API would only get the file from S3 and return it.

Comment: In the task we assume that the files size won't be a problem so we can store them in memory. My problem is that I don't know how to upload a file and wait for the API call - I suppose someone can call the methods repeatedly. Meanwhile I need the application be able to serve other file with some API method calls.